# Why is my overloaded << not returning any data?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a class that loads a `vector<unsigned char>` using Asio's asynchronous methods. I then overloaded the << operator to return that data.

The problem is that even though the buffer is full and valid, the operator does not return any data.

My buffer: `vector<unsigned char>read_buffer;`

Operator declaration:

```
friend std::vector<unsigned char> operator<<(const vector<unsigned char>output, const shared_ptr<Socket>socket) noexcept;
```

The implementation:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> operator<<(const vector<unsigned char>output,
                                           const shared_ptr<Socket>socket) noexcept {
      std::cerr << output.size() << std::endl;
      std::cerr << socket->read_buffer.size() << std::endl;
      return socket->read_buffer;
    }
```

where `std::cerr << socket->read_buffer.size() << std::endl;` has the right size and step by step debugging show its content is also valid.

But when I get data back:

```
vector<unsigned char> response;
response << socket;
```

`response` is empty. I've tried initialising it to the length of the expected response but I just end up with a buffer with X null characters.

Stumped by this. Shouldn't a return statement copy or move the value out?

Comment: Where do you fill `output` in the function?  Or any vector?  Also if you want to manipulate `output` it needs to be non const.

Comment: Is `read_buffer` a `vector`?

Comment: read_buffer is a vector<unsigned char>, filled with valid content. I don't fill output anywhere.

Comment: `response << socket;` ofc this is empty, you don't actually modify it (all you do is print its original size). Instead you return something from that expression. If you wanted to capture it from your current implementation (which is really odd I must say) you'd have to `auto x = response << socket;`

Comment: what you do is roughly equivalent to calling `operator<<(response,socket);` so you have to fill `response` / `output` in the function.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0434ea6463e594f5) may help you understand whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response << socket;
```

means

```
operator<<(response, socket);
```

and in this form it's clear that you're discarding the return value.

That the code compiles with a prototype that reads `const vector<unsigned char>output` is another hint that you're never modifying the output vector.

If you want this to work like the stream insertion operators - appending to the left-hand side and being chainable, like so:

```
 response << socket << another_socket;
```

the first parameter should be a non-const reference, and you should return a non-const reference to the same object:

```
vector<unsigned char>& operator<<(vector<unsigned char>& output,
                                  const shared_ptr<Socket>socket) noexcept 
{
      output.insert(output.end(), socket->read_buffer.begin(), socket->read_buffer.end());
      return output;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a false assumption on what is happening in

```
response << socket;
```

When you do the above the return of the `operator <<` is not assigned into `response`.  Instead response is the left hand side of the operator and socket is the right have side since it is a binary operator.  The return value itself would be captured doing something like

```
auto foo = response << socket;
```

But this isn't what you want to do.  What you want to do is treat the left hand side just like you would a stream object like `cout` and manipulate it directly.  The way we do that is by changing the signature and a little bit of the body of `operator <<`.  First we need to pass the vector in by reference since you want to modify it so we have

```
std::vector<unsigned char>& operator<<(const vector<unsigned char>& output,
                                       const shared_ptr<Socket>socket) noexcept
                          ^        lvalue references here         ^
```

And then we change the body to assign the vector from `socket` into `output` and then we return output like

```
{
    std::cerr << output.size() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << socket->read_buffer.size() << std::endl;
    output = socket->read_buffer;
    return output;
}
```

Really though I think it would be better just to do construction or assign instead of overloading an operator. You could just have

```
vector<unsigned char> response(socket->read_buffer);
// or
vector<unsigned char> response;
// stuff
response = socket->read_buffer;
```

In your main code.

Comment: I want to make read_buffer read only. I could add an accessor I guess, but then what's wrong with the operator overload?

Comment: @ruipacheco There is nothing wrong with overloading, I just do not see its need here.  If you want to do like molbdnilo has in his answer and actually just append the buffer into output then the stream operator would be appropriate.  If you are just doing assignment then I would use the already provided assignment methods.

Comment: If we use shift operators for IO why wouldn't my object? Seems natural and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code should look like this:

```
std::vector<unsigned char>& operator<<(vector<unsigned char>& output,
                                           const shared_ptr<Socket>socket) {
      std::cerr << output.size() << std::endl;
      std::cerr << socket->read_buffer.size() << std::endl;
      output = socket->read_buffer;
      return output;
    }
```

As it was mentioned in comments, the 1st parameter is the one taking the result of the operation, and you never change it. Also omit the `noexcept`, unless you guarantee there will be no exception thrown (e.g. embedding all the operations within a `try` / `catch` block).

Comment: These parameters would go better with `operator<<=`

Comment: @M.M IMO the whole operator overloading is questionable.